# Proportional move?

Tags: distort

If I have e.g a train track mesh, and I want to move one end of the track mesh down on the Y axis by a whole track width, is there a tool that would allow me to do this. I am aware of proportional scale and proportional rotation and have used these before to create twisted chair legs. What I would like to be able to do is like this but I'd just like to be able to do a loop select on the end edge, move it on the Y axis, and have all of the other edges along the track move down proportionally. Is there such a thing as proportional move as I can't see one? I've tried selecting every edge except the first, Y to split, and then tried moving the end edges but with no joy. It's not like I can scroll wheel with move to select the area I want to influence.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Proportional editing works for translate (grab) operations as well as rotate and scale operations.  Select your edge, enable proportional editing, and g y to grab constrainted to y axis.  You'll see the rest of the same mesh get affected proportionally.  (If they are separate meshes, make sure you don't have "connected" enabled in your operator panel.)

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I've just tried it and I can't get it to work.I'm using 2.8 if that makes any difference. Alt-select to select edge, g, then y, grabs it and locks it into y. Made sure proportional editing is selected. It just moves the edges I have selected. Strange. No scroll option to select size of affected area. Not that I care about that though, I just want to proportionally move the whole mesh.

Comment: Your suggestion works fine with a new project. For some reason it's unhappy with the mesh/file created in 2.79b within 2.8. Look like some of my verts are unselectable on the corners. Don't know how it's got messed up, but at least I know what to do now, thanks.